# find peaks in signal

Tags: scipy, signal-processing

how with the help of a scipy.signal.find_peaks I can select such sequences in the signal, if I know their total width?[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a width parameter in scripy.signal's find_peaks that you could try setting. 
If you know what the sequence looks like/ have the wav file you could fftconvolve the signal with the signal of this desired sequence to find matches.